# problem in using jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

i dont know what is actual problem in the below code, but it doesn't work as i expected.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        var uid="sekar@example.com";
        var upass="sample";
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'http://www.example.com/test.php',
            data: {
                em : uid,
                pass : upass,
                action : 'check'
            },
            success : function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(errorThrown);}
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' value='click' id='clickme' />
</body>

</html>
```

In that test.php i simply tried to `echo "hello world"` or `echo $_GET['action']` 
But none of this worked i got only empty message? can some one help me in this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: You should not pass passwords using `GET`. Secondly, are the pages on the same domain?

Comment: Can you post the test.php script?

Comment: I assume you're not actually using the URL: `http://www.example.com/test.php`

Comment: i think you are doing a cross-domain AJAX request which is not allowed due to security reasons.

Comment: @pimvdb No, i just created a test html pin client and accessed the test.php

Comment: @Jon Here is test.php content. <?php
$action=$_GET['action'];
echo $action;
echo "hio";
?>

Comment: @James Wiseman i tried this test.php locally and it worked, but when i tried in the above url it gives me the empty message. but when i tried to access the page on browser it echoes the test string.

Comment: i'm trying this for a firefox addon, i need to send some selected content to that test page. when user selects a content and clicks ok button it should be submitted to that test page. This addon is for my own use, to simplify my work i tried this, but no luck! have anyone got the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error in your code. But never pass your passwords using GET.
I create two files test.html and test.php.

```
Code of test.html:
<!-- language: html-->
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        var uid="sekar@example.com";
        var upass="sample";
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'test.php',
            data: {
                em : uid,
                pass : upass,
                action : 'check'
            },
            success : function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(errorThrown);}
        });
    });
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <input type='button' value='click' id='clickme' />
 </body>

 </html>

code of test.php:
<!-- language: php -->
 <?php
   echo $_GET['action'];
 ?>
```

Comment: @James Wiseman same thing i did, but it never worked, because this ajax code will be in client side [ firefox add on ], i tried it with full url but never worked... what should i do?

Comment: @Sekar: I only edited this post. I think you are confusing me with @user493376, who wrote the answer

Answer (score 1):

Is it because **data** has to be a string?

```
data: "em="+uid+"&pass="+upass="&action=check",
```